# Bring app to the front when notification is clicked

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add functionality to my foreground service notification to just open the app when the notification is clicked. I don't want to run any activity - I just want to display the app.
Basically I want to achieve same thing that can be achieved in Android by bringing list of apps and clicking on one).

I've checked lots of posts on StackOverflow, but all of them use activity class in Intent, while I don't care about any particular activity - I just want to bring the app up.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a launcher activity right? so you always can start an activity with your launcher activity and use a launch mode in the AndroidManifest.xml to define to bring it up if it already has been created.

Comment: By 'start an activity' - you mean start some specific activity ? If so - I was hoping to be able to just say 'just display whatever is active at the moment'.

Could you share an example if you have one ?

Comment: you can do it or you can get the launcher activity from your PackageManager, google how to do it